# Showing Map in a Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

In my application i want to show google map in a Fragment. My activity class is given below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.app_name,
            R.string.action_settings) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    onItemSelected(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public void onItemSelected(String link) {
    DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);

    fragment.setText(link);

}
```

}

As shown in the code in the Activity i am using a DrawyerLayout inside that there are four items. When the user press the Item. I am showing Fragment where the MapFragment kept inside.

Please see the Main Xml layout file.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    class="com.example.mynavigation.DetailFragment"
    android:visibility="invisible" >
</fragment>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My Fragment Class.

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

GoogleMap map ;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("kkkkkkkkkkkk");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rssitem_detail,

            container, true);
    return view;
}

public void setText(String item) {
    System.out.println("set Tewxt");
    TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);

    view.setText(item);

}
}
```

And the fragment_rssitem_detail.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detailsText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:text="Default Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30dip" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />
</FrameLayout>

<!-- <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.ListFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Android does not support nested fragment through xml. so you need to push fragment runtime in framelayout specified in xml.

Comment: Since i am new to android Fragments and Map please share me a good Tutorial or example program to clear this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: refer this one http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/gps-and-google-map-in-android-applications-series/

Answer (score 0):

Put only LinearLayout at where you want to put map in your xml and push map programatically as below:

```
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
addFragment(lnrMap.getId(), mapFragment); //lnrMap is your LinearLayout from xml.
googleMap = mapFragment.getExtendedMap();
```

AddFragment Method(),Put this method in your DetailFragment class:

```
public void addFragment(int layoutId, Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(layoutId, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```